# A callback in the React SFC with hooks receives old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Why the callback in the React Native Single Functional component based on react hooks always receives the Deprecated value of the **isNameInvalid** variable?

In the example below the *onChangeText* callback always receives False, even when it changes. The console.log above shows the correct value.

Why does it happen and how to solve it? Is it about closures? 
I thought the callback re-creates itself on each re-render thus I expected it to receive the correct value.

```
import * as React from 'react;
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native' 

export default function CommunityNameStep(props) {
  const [ communityName, setCommunityName ] = React.useState('');


  const nameLn = communityName.length;
  const isNameInvalid = nameLn > 25;


  // receives Updated and Fresh version
  console.log('render. isNameInvalid ->>> ', isNameInvalid)

  return (
    <View
    >

        <TextInput
          label="Community name"
          onChangeText={(text: string) => {
            // Always receives false even when it true. In short: always Old value
            console.log('CALLBACK ->>> isNameInvalid', isNameInvalid);
              setCommunityName(text);
          }}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, it is not very clear what the problem is... When are you expecting the callback to return true? If you add a character more than the allowedNameLength will the callback  start to actually do what you want? Or it will return false whatsoever?

Comment: I think you need state for "isNameValid" for holding the updated value. You are getting correct value outside the return block because of the check you have applied.

Comment: react is all about state and lifecycle, you are not updating the `isNameInvalid` so its not updating, i have created a basic example for you check this out for more clarification: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-silence-evs15?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I updated the question by the direct length variable. 
@bakar_dev - it updates itself on each re-render when the communityName changes. Console.log in the body function works fine and shows the correct value but the console.log in the callback onChangeText - doesn't

Answer (score 1):

In React, rerenders are triggered whenever the state change. You triggered the render when you wrote the following line inside your callback

```
setCommunityName(text);
```

This means that when the callback is fired, the values inside will still be the same of the last render. After the callback has ended, it will rerender and the values will be updated. When you type the character that will make the `isNameInvalid` clause true, you should see the following inside the console log:

```
CALLBACK ->>> isNameInvalid false    // isNameInvalid was false before this callback
render. isNameInvalid ->>> true      // The component has rerendered and the value is now updated
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Drago96. Coud you, please, clarify one thing:  If the callback uses the value of the last render so why it always receives the False. Following your explanation, it should receive the correct value on the next render, after the **isNameInvalid**  became True.  But it looks like it Never receives the correct value somehow and could you, please, suggest how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Velidan It shouldn't always give you false indeed. What kind of components are View and TextInput? I made this slightly semplified example, and it works like it should, try checking it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shirley-c0jjr?file=/src/CommunityNameStep.js